# Eclipse Kepler - Glassfish Plugin - unable to start GF 3.1

Tags: glassfish, eclipse-kepler

I'm using Eclipse Kepler WTP + the Glassfish Kepler plugins.

Problem is I'm not able to start my locally installed Glassfish any more with this configuration.

After run the launch configuration the progress bar is at 69% and does not continue. There is nothing in the logs etc. I also tried using a fresh workspace etc. but no success.

The Glassfish version I'm running is 3.1.2. With Eclipse Juno and the corresponding Glassfish plugins everything works just fine.

**EDIT** Seems to be an issue with the already existing domain inside GF. It is possible to use the plugin when creating a new domain.

Comment: I have now the same problem... previosly I used Juno and since Glassfish-Tools don´t work for me in Kepler I didn´t do the migration yet. Now I made a big mistake: A updated the Glassfishtools-Plugin in Juno.... OMG, my only working solution isn´t working anymore. I´ll try your advice with creating a new domain.

Comment: It worked!! I would really like to know what causes the problem - now I´ve to reconfigure my datasources, realms and so on...

Comment: Starting with the knowledge that it´s obviously working with a clean new domain I started experimenting. I copied the configuration of the new domain to the old and the old was working. I tracked it now down to my JRebel-agent. I had integrated v. 5.1 und upgraded to 5.3 an now everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Same problem here, also an Eclipse Kepler user.

Answer (score 1):

Today I encountered the very same problem. For some reason, The Glassfish plugin couldn't start the domain - progess bar at 69%. A while after it stopped because of a time out. I don't know why it couldn't start.

- Open the asadmin console : {GLASSFISH_DIRECTORY}/bin/asadmin
- execute the `start-domain` command
- Refresh the eclipse Glassfish plugin if needed. You can see that the server has been launched properly.

I know, it doesn't fix the problem. But do remember that the Glassfish plugin only provides a GUI. Command lines are still working if the plugin is not.

(Actually I don't want to create a domain again...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is eclipse cannot connect to your jmx glassfish port.

Look in your glassfish console por the jmx port where jmx admin service is listening, somethin like this:

`2014-01-13T11:08:38.935+0100|Información: JMX005: JMXStartupService had Started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://mywks:8686/jndi/rmi://mywks:8686/jmxrmi`

Check this port is running:

```
telnet mywks 8686
```

If the port is ok, the problem is eclipse can't connect to port using machine name , in my case the problem was due to proxy configuration.

Open eclipse proxy configuration (windows -> preferences -> network connection), try changing active provicer to "manual" and configure your proxy. If proxy is not the problem, you can try to configure your local machine name as local host loop in your etc/host file.

(Note changing your proxy settings can cause your eclipse stops accessing eclipse market place).

If this not resolves the problem, try to sniff eclipse to glassfish connection using wireshark.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have forgotten to fill in the root directory as Glassfish. Do that in the setting enviroment for the server in Eclipse.